# Checksums, Data Integrity

Tags: c++, arrays, data-integrity

the  pseudocode for this assignment is essentually:
1. Open the specified file in binary mode
2. Save the file name in the fileNames array.
3. Determine the file size using seekg and tellg
4. Read the file contents into the character array in one statement
5. Close the file
6. Loop through the array, one character at a time and accumulate the sum of each byte
7. Store the sum into the checkSums array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
//declare variables
string filePath;
void savefile();
char choice;
int i, a, b, sum;
sum = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
ifstream inFile;
//arrays
const int SUM_ARR_SZ = 100;
string fileNames[SUM_ARR_SZ];
unsigned int checkSums[SUM_ARR_SZ];
do {
    cout << "Please select: " << endl;
    cout << "   A) Compute checksum of specified file" << endl;
    cout << "   B) Verify integrity of specified file" << endl;
    cout << "   Q) Quit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
    {
        //open file in binary mode
        cout << "Specify the file path: " << endl;
        cin >> filePath;
        inFile.open(filePath.c_str(), ios::binary);

        //save file name
        fileNames[a] = filePath;
        a++;


        //use seekg and tellg to determine file size
        char Arr[100000];
        inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
        int fileLen = inFile.tellg();
        inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
        inFile.read(Arr, fileLen);
        inFile.close();
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            sum += Arr[i];
        }
        //store the sum into checkSums array
        checkSums[b] = sum;
        b++;
        cout << "    File checksum = " << sum << endl;

    }
    if (choice == 'b' || choice == 'B')
    {
        cout << "Specify the file path: " << endl;
        cin >> filePath;
        if (strcmp(filePath.c_str(), fileNames[a].c_str()) == 0)
        {

        }
    }
} while (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q');
system("pause");
}
```

I'm getting values like "-540000"  and I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. You're creating an array on the stack without zeroing its contents, so `Arr` will contain "garbage" data.
2. You're creating the buffer with a fixed size, which means you're wasting space if the file is smaller than 100,000 bytes and you can't process a file that's larger than 100,000 bytes (without reusing the buffer)
3. You iterate over every byte in the buffer instead of those bytes that represent the file if it's smaller than 100,000 bytes.
4. I also note you're mixing C and C++ string functions. You don't need to call C's `strcmp` if you're using `string` then use `string::compare`.
5. C++ does not require forward-declaration of local variables, your code would be cleaner if you only declared local variables when they're used, instead of all-at-once.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to c++ programming and I cannot get the teacher to email me back for help.